# Huge memory usage in Javascript (DAWG)

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten, webassembly

I am working on implementation of DAWG algorithm in my project. I am using `emscripten` to convert it into `webassembly`.

Library Link: [here](http://code.google.com/p/dawgdic/)

`./emcc -g test/dawg-builder-test.bc -o dawg.html -s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["ccall", "cwrap"]' -g4 -O2`

I need to store multiple string of hostnames like this

`"lequipe.fr|ilgiornale.it|sportmediaset.mediaset.it|meteo.it|ilmessaggero.it|ilmattino.it|today.it|romatoday.it|lavanguardia.com|lalsace.fr|fussballtransfers.com|lejsl.com|bienpublic.com|dna.fr|leprogres.fr|ledauphine.com|estrepublicain.fr|vosgesmatin.fr|footmercato.net|fichajes.com|abc.es|buzzfeed.com|pcworld.es|buzzfeednews.com|macworld.co.uk|cio.co.uk|computerworlduk.com........"`

When I load `webassembly` in javascript and load data then HEAP size become too high..and I see lots of indexes with value 0.

Please find sample extension code with dawg implementation [here](https://github.com/Nitin-Er/DawgTest). In [screenshot](https://demophp.digi-corp.com/nitin/error1.png), You can find details of memory allocation. Follow below steps to check memory allocation.

1. Manually load extension in chrome browser.
2. Go to chrome://extensions/ tab
3. Find DAWG 2 extension block
4. Click on background page link, Chrome Devtools will get opened.
5. Go to memory tab.
6. Take a heap short.

Comment: I was under the impression that emscripten pre-allocates a huge array anyway.

Comment: It's just around 18MB of buffer, which is not really huge though. I will post explanation soon.

Comment: I have lot of data to be inserted in DAWG. It makes my browser run very slow. I am wondering why data is not sequentially stored in HEAP array? How can I optimize my webassembly binary to reduce TOTAL_MEMORY for initial run?